# Plotly marker line color based on dataframe column category

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following example df:

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     1    10    C
1     2    15    A
2     3    20    A
3     4    25    A
4     5    30    B
5     6    35    B
6     7    40    B
7     8    45    B
8     9    50    B
9    10    55    B
```

And here is my simple code for the scatter plot below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas aspd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})
fig = px.scatter(df, x='col1', y='col2', color='col3')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12))        
fig.show()
```

The plot separates the colors of markers from `col3`, however, I would like to make a plot with markers that are not filled with any color, but rather have the marker line colors from `col3`.

[image]

Comment: Does the plot have to use plotly express or you are okay using plotly graph_objects?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't really matter, graph_objects will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in fact happy with what your example code does with regards to color attribution based on `'col3':['C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']`, then you can just add the following line to your snippet to produce circles with the same colors as the original markers, and *no* markers. In other words, holes in the middle:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker_line_color = t.marker.color, marker_line_width = 15,
                                  marker_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],

                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})


fig = px.scatter(df, x='col1', y='col2', color='col3')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8))        
fig.show()

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(marker_line_color = t.marker.color, marker_line_width = 15,
                                      marker_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, I believe you are okay using plotly.graph_objects.

Here, I am using `map` to assign a different color for each unique value in `df.col3` (A, B, C). While plotting the scatter plot, you can set the marker fill color to transparent by using the `rgba` (where a = alpha = transparency) to 0, meaning fully transparent

Then, using the `line` (which is the border line to map to the color you want - in this case the `col3.map(colors)`. You can also set the width of the edge line... Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})

import plotly.graph_objects as go
colors={'A':'red', 'B':'blue', 'C':'green'}
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.col1, y=df.col2, 
                         marker=dict(size=12, color='rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                                     line=dict(color=df['col3'].map(colors), width=3))))
```

**Output Plot**

[image]

**OPTION 2**

Here, I have modified the code so that the `colors` dictionary now picks up all the unique values from the input dataframe-col3. As we don't know the count of the unique values, I am using a colormap (plasma) to set the colors for the lines. You do need to add the `colorscale` to this. You can of course choose a colormap to your liking. Hope this helps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                'col2':[10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55],
                'col3':['C','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B']})

colors=dict(zip(df.col3.unique(), np.linspace(0,1,df.col3.nunique())))

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.col1, y=df.col2, 
                         marker=dict(size=12, color='rgba(255,255,255,0)', 
                                     line=dict(color=df['col3'].map(colors), colorscale='plasma', width=3))))
```

**Output Plot 2**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I was wondering if we can accomplish without explicitly mapping the colors for each category, since their number may vary. In this case, it is A,B,C. It can be D,E,A or sth like that

Comment: I think you can. Assigning a color to each unique value and using colorscale. Let me update the response, give me some time

Comment: Check the updates under **OPTION 2**

Comment: Thanks @Redox. This was the approach in my mind too.